# How to set the Castle Windsor NoTrackingReleasePolicy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, lifecycle

I know it's not the recommended way but I wanted to know how you go about setting the NoTrackingReleasePolicy for the Castle Windsor lifecycle policy?

I can see plenty of documentation on explains what it is and why it may be used but I can't see how it is actually implemented.

Using this with C# and Castle version 3.3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this behaviour is deprecated.

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy = new NoTrackingReleasePolicy();
```